# Как подгрузить несколько файлов конфигурации Spring?

Tags: java, spring, файлы, config

Сейчас изучаю Spring И нашёл пример переключения профилей через использование 2-х файлов конфигурации.
Для их подключения используется такой код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако, при попытке написания такого же примера, вылетает ошибка, что Spring не может найти эти файлы

```
public class DemoApplication{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load(new PathResource("meta/*-food.xml"));
    ctx.refresh();
}
```

}

Или же так:

public class DemoApplication{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("meta/*-food.xml");
    ctx.refresh();
}
```

}

В первом ошибка:

> Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 5: meta/*-food.xml

Во втором:

> Could not resolve bean definition resource pattern [meta/*-food.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException

Файлы на месте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

```
GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("classpath:meta/*-food.xml");
```

А файлы конфигурации перенесите в пакет `resources/meta`